# Identifier 'reducer' already declared

Tags: javascript, react-native

On line 7 where reducer is declared, I'm getting the error: "Identifier 'reducer' has already been declared". I'm about to try deleting it and writing it out again piece by piece, but if you see my issue, then let me know!

Thanks!

```
import React, { reducer } from 'react';
import { View, Button, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import ColorCounter from '../components/ColorCounter';

const COLOR_INCREMENT = 15;

const reducer = (state, action) => { 
    // state === { red: number, green: number, blue: number }
    // action === { colorToChange: 'red' || 'green' || 'blue' }

    switch (action.colorToChange) {
    case 'red': 
        return { ...state, red: state.red + action.amount };
    case 'green':
        return { ...state, green: state.green + action.amount };
    case 'blue':
        return { ...state, blue: state.blue + action.amount };
    default:
        return state;
    }
};

const SquareScreen = () => {
    const [state, runMyReducer] = useReducer(reducer, { red 0, green 0, blue 0 });
    const { red, green, blue } = state;

    return (
        <View>
            <ColorCounter 
                onIncrease={() => runMyReducer({ colorToChange: 'red', amount: COLOR_INCREMENT })} 
                onDecrease={() => runMyReducer({ colorToChange: 'red', amount: -1 * COLOR_INCREMENT })} 
                color="Red" 
            />
            <ColorCounter 
                onIncrease={() => runMyReducer({ colorToChange: 'green', amount: COLOR_INCREMENT })} 
                onDecrease={() => runMyReducer({ colorToChange: 'green', amount: -1 * COLOR_INCREMENT })}  
                color="Green" 
            />
            <ColorCounter 
                onIncrease={() => runMyReducer({ colorToChange: 'blue', amount: COLOR_INCREMENT })} 
                onDecrease={() => runMyReducer({ colorToChange: 'blue', amount: -1 * COLOR_INCREMENT })} 
                color="Blue" 
            />
            <View 
                style={{ 
                    height: 150, 
                    width: 150, 
                    backgroundColor: `rgb(${red}, ${green}, ${blue})`
                }} 
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles=StyleSheet.create({});

export default SquareScreen;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's declared in the 1st line:

`import React, { reducer } from 'react';`

Comment: Okay, I tried removing the import function and alternatively removing the const before the declaration. Both give me an error on line 24: "Unexpected token, expected ','

```
const SquareScreen = () => {
> 24 |  const [state, runMyReducer] = useReducer(reducer, { red 0, green 0, blue 0 });
```

Comment: try: `import React from 'react';`

Comment: That gives me the previously stated error. With the error arrow pointing to the 0 after red on line 24.

Comment: Got it working! Needed to import {useReducer}, not {reducer}, and add colons to line 24 `red: 0` Thanks!